# Securely querying data with firestore - Permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm facing a permission denied error when querying firestore, when I have introduced a rule. I have narrowed down my complex rule and filter to the below 2 examples of which one query works, and one doesn't. I do not understand what is wrong with my failing query.

From https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-query I understand that a rule is not a filter. According to this document: "If a query could potentially return documents that the client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.".

Baring that in mind, I have been iterating over my rule, filter and data, and come with the below:

**The data:**
I have NO data in my collection called "MyCollection". As a matter of fact, the collection "MyCollection" has never existed.

**The rule:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /MyCollection/{id} {
      allow read: if (  
                       (resource.data.readAccess == 0)
                     )

      allow write: if (true)

    }
  }
}
```

**My failing query (where I have the permission denied error):**

```
Firestore.instance.collection('MyCollection')
      .where("readAccess", isLessThanOrEqualTo: 0)
      .getDocuments()
      .then((_) => print("Success!"));
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
W/Firestore(12491): (21.3.0) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(MyCollection where readAccess <= 0) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

**My successfull query:**
(The only difference in this query is that I replaced "isLessThanOrEqualTo" with isEqualTo)

```
Firestore.instance.collection('MyCollection')
      .where("readAccess", isEqualTo: 0)
      .getDocuments()
      .then((_) => print("Success!"));
```

**Comments:**

- I have the same results when I do populate MyCollection with data.
- It looks like the query is validated against the rule, not the "potential return documents" as the document https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/rules-query states. If this is the case I wonder how I will be able to translate the following rule into a filter:

  ```
                 (resource.data.readAccess == 0) || 
                 ((request.auth != null) && 
                  (resource.data.readAccess <= get(/databases/$(database)/documents/App/$(resource.data.appId)).data.group[request.auth.uid])
                 )
  ```
- This rule is fairly similar, except that it validates the readAccess level of a document against the group access level in the "App" document for that data's app, for the logged on user. If I can't match the query for a simple rule, I can't imagine what I need to do for this complex rule.

Please advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With security rules, the query must exactly match the rules.  The behavior you're observe is exactly what I would expect.

With a rule like this:

```
allow read: if resource.data.readAccess == 0;
```

That means the query must be filtered exactly like this;

```
where("readAccess", isEqualTo: 0)
```

Nothing else will satisfy this rule.  It's absolutely **demands** that the query filter for exactly the value of 0 on the readAccess field.  It's not clear to me why you're expecting a different outcome.

Your query suggests that the client provide its own "access" to the collection.  Note that this is not secure.  You can't depend on client apps self-reporting their own level of access in a database query.  Something else on the backend needs to determine if the app is allowed to make the query.

Typically, Firebase Authentication is used to determine who the user is, then allow access based on what that user is allowed to do.  You could store the user's permissions somewhere in another document, and use the contents of that document to determine what they can do.  Or perhaps use custom claims.  But you can't trust the the user pass their own permissions.

Comment: What do you mean that a query must exactly match permissions? This would mean that any time you check if the user is logged in, or if you are checking a data variable in the resource object, then the query must have those things as well. 

Doesn't checking if the user has permissions to read/write in the table in question almost always involve doing something that is not in the query?

Comment: Yes, it involves looking at request,auth and possibly other documents.

Comment: Then the query does not match the permissions as the query is not calling for documents only where the user has permissions in those other documents? Or is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that question.  If your rule doesn't indicate anything about the user, then there is no security based on the user.  Perhaps you want to start with the documentation on that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Comment: What I mean is that if you store "permissions" in a separate table, the query sent from the client does not have the condition that the user have permissions in that table. It is something that is handled on the back end.

Comment: You can use the contents of other documents in security rules.  The rules themselves can access any document you want - the user does not need read permission. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents